# iText and color profiles

Tags: java, pdf, colors, itext, profile

I'm creating a PDF using iText's PdfStamper and I'd like to apply different color profiles. I've only seen examples of this using PdfWriter but it seems like a PdfStamper has an underlying PdfWriter which you can get by `getWriter()`. I'm using the code below but it doesn't seem to apply the color profile.

```
PdfWriter pdfwriter = outputPDF.getWriter();
String profileName = this._renderVO.getProfileName();
String profilePath = this._renderVO.getProfilePath();
ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream(profilePath));
pdfwriter.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", profileName, icc);
```

Is setOutputIntents all you need to call to apply a profile?

thanks!

Comment: are you certain profilePath and profileName are correct? I would log what those values are as a starting point.